# GA4 "items" parameter has started becoming empty

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-4

We have been using ecommerce events for GA4 exactly as specified in Google's documentation for a long time, and so far everything has been working well. However, after June 22nd, 2023, the "items" array for the "view_item_list" event has started becoming empty for iOS in GA4. Everything was working fine before June 22nd, but then it suddenly stopped populating any values inside the “items”.

We have already checked our application and everything is being fired correctly on the backend. Additionally, there have been no new releases for our iOS application around June 22nd. We also checked if the problem only affects certain app versions, but there is no consistent pattern.

Therefore, we suspect that something might have changed on GA4's side. However, we checked GA4's releases to see if any changes could be affecting the "view_item_list" event, but we couldn't find anything.

We also didn't change anything on our GA configuration.

Does anyone else have the same issue, or could someone help identify the problem and suggest a solution?